# Magento table rates disable after certain amount

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento's table rates. And they work fine.

I use the "Weight (and above)" setting.

But now my question is this: I would like to disable the Table Rates if the ordered amount is > $10.000.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to override or subclass /app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php
Specifically look at the `collectRates()` method, here you can get access to the current quote/cart and make determinations based on price and other factors.